# .desktop files not being processed by nautilus

Tags: gnome, nautilus, icons, .desktop

I have `Show desktop icons` enabled, but still nautilus cannot show the desktop icons for the relevant applications. This happens with Budgie and Gnome shell. Nemo is able to show the application icons though.

I think this broke (at least for me) with Nautilus 3.24.x. My Gnome version is 3.24, Ubuntu Gnome 17.04 with ppas, nautilus is 3.24.1. Here is a sample `emacs.desktop` file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=GNU Emacs
GenericName=Text Editor
Comment=Edit text
MimeType=text/english;text/plain;text/x-makefile;text/x-c++hdr;text/x-c++src;text/x-chdr;text/x-csrc;text/x-java;text/x-moc;text/x-pascal;text/x-tcl;text/x-tex;application/x-shellscript;text/x-c;text/x-c++;
Exec=emacs %F
Icon=emacs
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Categories=Development;TextEditor;
StartupWMClass=Emacs
Keywords=Text;Editor;
```

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Note that Telegram works since it is a binary file.

Comment: Are the files executable?

Comment: @muru Yes, they are.

Comment: You have `;` at the end of some lines. From looking at some of other `.desktop` files most of them have no trailing `;`. While that might not be the issue, consider following the format that's consistent with other `.desktop` files.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I happened to stumble upon the answer by change. Right-click upon a `.desktop` icon file, and `nautilus` shows the following confirmation dialog.

[image]

Clicking `Trust and Launch` enables the icon.

Comment: This performs exactly same thing as `chmod +x` in terminal, which means the file wasn't originally executable. Your [comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/940188/desktop-files-not-being-processed-by-nautilus#comment1492159_940188)  in response to muru was misleading. But glad you finally found the solution.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy I know that they need to be executables, and I had checked that fact. It is easy for me now to reproduce it. Can we attach pictures to comments?

Comment: No, comments are limited, but you can always upload something to imgur and pasye link here